# How to handle parallel upsert error in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

There is a workaround in our project to handle duplicate key error when two threads are doing upsert:

```
try:
    await db.collection.find_one_and_update(query, update, upsert=True)
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    await db.collection.find_one_and_update(query, update, upsert=True)
```

It is working correctly, but maybe there is a better way? Also, why does this error occure? Why Mongo cant handle it on it's side (do upsert in one query and do update in other) and we have to do it in our application code?

Comment: From my understanding, it happens because MongoDB submit the query to the storage engine (insert) because the document is not found - not in the index - at the same moment. So it performs 2 inserts, and one of them fails.

Comment: See official statement here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21006 . I suggest you change your application design to create the (empty) document before your application threads operations to update it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and link. Hm, I think we have some queries that can be rewritten, but some can't. We will think about it.

Comment: @Sanya note that this behaviour will improve in the upcoming MongoDB 4.2 as described in here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322. If it's safe to do so, in 4.2 this will be automatically retried.